# One to Many Relation, One PK but many ForeignKeys, exception while adding a new migration

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys, one-to-many, data-annotations

I have problem with relation one to many, EF 6 with Data Annotations. When I look at the similar problems the main model has many Primary Keys, but with my situation I have only one PK but still exception occurs while adding a new migration and I don't know why.

> ```
> Data1_SomeEntity_Target_Data1_SomeEntity_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependentand Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.
> ```

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Data1> Data1 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Data2> Data2 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Data3> Data3 { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Data4> Data4 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Request100")]
    public long? Request100Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Request100 Request100 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Request200")]
    public long? Request200Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Request200 Request200 { get; set; }
}

public class Data1
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [MinLength(1), MaxLength(1000)]
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SomeClass")]
    public long? SomeClassId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Data2")]
    public long? Data2Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Data3")]
    public long? Data3Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SomeEntity")]
    public long? SomeEntityId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual SomeClass SomeClass { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Data2 Data2 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Data3 Data3 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual SomeEntity SomeEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your SomeEntity class should have only one Data - Data1 collection and you can add some navigations too

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Data1.SomeEntity))]
    public ICollection<Data1> Data1s { get; set; }

    
    [ForeignKey("Request100")]
    public long? Request100Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Request100 Request100 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Request200")]
    public long? Request200Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Request200 Request200 { get; set; }
}
```

SomeClass , Data2, Data3 should be configured the same way